Not able to do UPI payment using third party app
I am working on a project where I have a requirement to scan a UPI QR code and do the UPI payment by invoking UPI apps using Intent. Everything is working fine except I am not able to pay successfully, the payment failed with this error "exceeded bank limit for this payment".
I tried to scan the same QR code with UPI app integrated scanner it's working fine but it's not working with my app or any other scanner.
One thing that is weird is when I am doing payment through banking app it's working fine but not with Gpay/Paytm UPI apps.
Please help me with this, I am stuck with this and not able continue my project.
